# name of a tcltest test under execution

Tags: unit-testing, scripting, tcl, stack-trace

I want to obtain the name of a `tcltest` `test` currently being executed in a `Tcl` script. For example, the following code is supposed to print the name of the test:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
package require tcltest

tcltest::test testFunction {} -body {
    puts [lindex [info level 0] 0]
    set a 1
} -result 1
```

but, it gives the following error:

```
==== testFunction  FAILED
==== Contents of test case:

    puts [lindex [info level 0] 0]
    set a 1

---- Test generated error; Return code was: 1
---- Return code should have been one of: 0 2
---- errorInfo: bad level "0"
    while executing
"info level 0"
    ("uplevel" body line 2)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1 $script"
---- errorCode: TCL LOOKUP STACK_LEVEL 0
==== testFunction FAILED
```

There must be some basic mistake I am doing, any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the use case for getting this by introspection? It would seem to me that a good test body would not need to know (there are other facilities in tcltest for temporary files and directories, so the naming of those is a non-issue).

Comment: @DonalFellows: You may be right, introspection doesn't seem to be much useful here. Actually, the test case needs to know its name because I want to generate a report where the name of the test case will be a parameter, in fact, the report might contain multiple test case information generated from a test suite run. Since it is not likely that the name of the test case will change frequently (or at least once for that matter), hard-coding the name is a better option I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find any such introspection (didn't look very hard). I did look, since I wanted to log running tests and mark the transition from one test to another.

There is nothing to stop you from knowing the test names anyway, of course.

```
namespace eval ::testname {
    variable name foo
    variable major 1
    variable minor 0
    proc curname {} {
        variable name
        variable major
        variable minor
        return $name-$major.$minor
    }
}

set ::testname::name testfunction

::tcltest::test [::testname::curname] {} -body {
    puts [::testname::curname]
} -cleanup {
    incr ::testname::minor
}

::tcltest::test [::testname::curname] {} -body {
    puts [::testname::curname]
} -cleanup {
    incr ::testname::minor
}
```

or

```
oo::object create testname
oo::objdefine testname {
    variable name major minor
    method init {nam {maj 1} {min 0}} {
        set name $nam
        set major $maj
        set minor $min
    }
    method name val {set name $val}
    method major val {set minor 0 ; set major $val}
    method minor val {set minor $val}
    method bump {} {incr minor}
    method curname {} {return $name-$major.$minor}
}

testname init testfunction

::tcltest::test [testname curname] {} -body {
    puts [testname curname]
} -cleanup {
    testname bump
}

::tcltest::test [testname curname] {} -body {
    puts [testname curname]
} -cleanup {
    testname bump
}
```

(This is improvised code, not something I actually use, but it is tested once and does at least run.)

Documentation:
[create (method of `oo::class`)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/class.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[method (object configuration subcommand)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm),
[oo::objdefine](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[oo::object](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/object.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[tcltest (package)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tcltest.htm),
[variable (object slot subcommand)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)

Comment: I never use automatically-generated names for tests I write. This is because I want to be able to use the test name as something I can grep for when dealing with a failure.

Comment: @DonalFellows: that's basically why I don't use them, either. In the case I mention in my answer, I ended up using log lines that repeated the test name literally. The ability to introspect the test name would have been helpful.

Comment: @PeterLewerin: This is indeed a nice example of auto-generation of test names, but I cannot say I was looking for something like this. The way I see it, it is not exactly an example of introspection of the test name, rather it is like fetching the name from the same source which was used to provide the name in the first place. It is somewhat similar to hard-coding the name in both the places (given that we don't want auto-generated names), which might be the easiest solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been awhile since this question was posted.

Since/If you just need it output for your report and not as a variable within the TCL environment, perhaps configuring tcltest with '-verbose start' could also work? ()

Example:

```
% package require tcltest
2.4.1
% ::tcltest::verbose start
start
% ::tcltest::test the_test {} -body { return 1 } -result 1
---- the_test start
% ::tcltest::verbose "start pass"
start pass
% ::tcltest::test the_test {} -body { return 1 } -result 1
---- the_test start
++++ the_test PASSED
```